# Rails: Datatables JSON error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, datatable

I am trying to follow the Railscasts tutorial 340 to populate a JQuery Datatables component from server-side JSON data.  The link to the tutorial is: http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables.  I am customising the code to work with my own database table and data.

When I attempt to visit the link which should output the JSON to the datatable, I get the following error:

```
not opened for reading
```

The code in the controller which handles the request is as follows:

```
class DatadescriptionController < ApplicationController
layout "datadescription"

def index
respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: DatasetIndexDatatable.new(view_context) }
    end
  end
end
```

and the DatasetIndexDatatable class which is instantiated in the format.json command looks like this:

```
class DatasetIndexDatatable
  delegate :params, :h, :link_to, :number_to_currency, to: :@view

  def initialize(view)
    @view = view
  end

  def as_json(options = {})
    {
    sEcho: params[:sEcho].to_i,
    iTotalRecords: Datadescription.count,
    iTotalDisplayRecords: datasets.total_entries,
    aaData: data
    }
 end

 private

def data
 datasets.map do |dataset|
   [
    id,
    database,
    table,
    created_by,
    name
  ]
  end
end

def datasets
  @datasets ||= fetch_datasets
end

def fetch_datasets
  datasets = Datadescription.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
  datasets = datasets.page(page).per_page(per_page)
  if params[:sSearch].present?
    datasets = datasets.where("name like :search or created_by like :search", search: "%#  {params[:sSearch]}%")
end
datasets
end

def page
  params[:iDisplayStart].to_i/per_page + 1
end

def per_page
  params[:iDisplayLength].to_i > 0 ? params[:iDisplayLength].to_i : 10
end

def sort_column
  columns = %w[id database table created_by name]
  columns[params[:iSortCol_0].to_i]
end

def sort_direction
  params[:sSortDir_0] == "desc" ? "desc" : "asc"
end

end
```

Can anyone shed any light on what this 'not opened for reading' error means and how I can correct my code to output the json as intended?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem.  The version of the code that was running was not the code that I posted due to a saving error.